# How to capture the value of a dynamically generated column in the database using JPA (hibernate)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have the following JPA entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "places")
public class Place {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

And a Spring repository called PlacesRepository which have a native query:

```
public interface PlacesRepository extends CrudRepository<Place, Long> {

    @Query(
        value = "SELECT *, DISTANCE(lat,lng,:myLat,:myLng) AS distance " +
                "FROM places ORDER BY distance",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    List<Place> nearestPlaces(
        @Param("myLat") double myLat,
        @Param("myLng") double myLng
    );

}
```

That DISTANCE function is just to exemplify a native database function. Since I'm using PostGIS, it would be equivalent to ST_Distance. It returns the distance using the coordinates of each record and those of the method.

How do I capture that "distance" field without having to store it in the table??? I don't want to store it because it is dynamic. I just want to return it with the entity as a json.

Answer (score 1):

An option here is to use HQL, not a native query. For example, you can create a simple result class:

```java
class PlaceToDistancePair {
    private Place place;
    private double distance;
    public PlaceToDistancePair(Place place, double distance) {
        this.place = place;
        this.distance = distance;
    }
// getters and setters
}
```

and then your @Query will look somehow like this:

```java
@Query(
        value = "SELECT new PlaceToDistancePair(p, DISTANCE(lat,lng,:myLat,:myLng)) FROM places p")
List<PlaceToDistancePair> placeToDistanceList;
```

You can find more about `select new` [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause) and also there you will find `select new map` construction, which maybe can also be suitable for you to map Place to distance without `PlaceToDistancePair` class.

However, in case your function (e.g. ST_Distance) is not registered in the hibernate dialect, you need to register it yourself. Check [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sql-function-jpql-criteria-api-query/) how Vlad does this in the "Registering the SQL function with the Hibernate Dialect" section.

Also an option for you is to use CriteriaBuilder API, which is much more flexible, but requires more code. Read [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria-typedquery-wrapper) for more

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. I'm sorry for answering so late.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try this:

```
List list = em
          .createQuery("SELECT FUNCTION("'"+myLat+"'"+",'"+myLng+"')"
                  + " FROM schemaName")
          .getResultList();
```

source [excample from web site](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/jpql-calling-database-functions.html)

In this situation you get data from your own function. Is possible set to this function all query question which you need. Not only DISTANCE but all data which you would like to get.